# Accessing functions between two .csproj files in the same application

Tags: c#, .net, api, csproj

I incorporated a WLAN API given from Codeplex's Managed WiFi site into my C# project (Windows Form Application). In the API, different functions are given to retrieve various aspects of the machine's current WiFi profile. I am only interested in retrieving the RSSI strength given in the function below. I then want to take that value and stick it in a text box on my form.

(Visual Studio 2008)

In WlanAPI.cs file, the function I am interested in exists as such:

```
 namespace NativeWifi
{
   public class WlanClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a Wifi network interface.
    /// </summary>
    public class WlanInterface
    {

                   /// <summary>
        /// Gets the RSSI.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The RSSI.</value>
        /// <remarks>Not supported on Windows XP SP2.</remarks>
        public int RSSI
        {
            get
            {
                return GetInterfaceInt(Wlan.WlanIntfOpcode.RSSI);
            }
        }
```

In myApp.cs I have a textbox simply named 'wifi' that will display the current RSSI. 
I have included : 'using NativeWifi' in myApp.cs header, but can't seem to get the data from the RSSI function in the WlanAPI.csproj. The project builds and compiles just fine. I'm just snagged on getting the RSSI value.

In myApp.cs I have a statement to the effect of:

```
wifi.Text = (GetInterfaceInt(Wlan.WlanIntfOpcode.RSSI)); //app form txt_box=RSSI value
```

I know this is incorrect, but shows what I am trying to do.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message, if any? And can you confirm if you have added a reference to WlanAPI in your project?

Comment: The error message I get is: Error 1 the name 'GetInterfaceInt' does not exist in the current context. I have the namespace reference where the rssi function lives in my project, but no direct reference to WlanApi.

Comment: There seems to be a disconnect here, the error you are mentioning is a compilation error (which can be duly resolved by adding a reference to the WlanApi project, assuming that your actual code uses GetInterfaceInt via RSSI property and through WlanInterface object obtained by using Interfaces property of a WlanClient object) but at the same time you mentioned in your question that it is building and compiling fine...

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to solve the problems you are facing by

1. Adding a reference to WlanAPI.dll or WlanAPI project (if you add it to your solution)
2. Using code like following:

   ```
   Using NativeWifi;

   Class MyAPP : Form
   {

     public void PrintRSSI()
     {

         WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
         var interfaces = client.Interfaces;

         //Now chose an interface out of all the available interfaces. Usually there would be zero or 1 interfaces available
         if(interfaces.Length > 0)
         {
             //Select first available interface. A more complicated logic can present the list of available interfaces to the user and and then display RSSI for the selected interface
             wifi.Text = interfaces[0].RSSI.ToString();
         }
      }

    //Other code for the class
   }
   ```

Comment: I added the reference to the project and ran your code. The error I get is: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to string

Comment: I ran int rssi = interfaces[0].RSSI;
                wifi.Text = rssi.ToString(); Just got a blank box

Comment: 'int' to string error was my fault, RSSI is int and should be converted to string before assigning it to text. I have edited my answer. Regarding getting a blank box, try putting a break-point and see what value of RSSI, you are getting.